# Is it possible to include Firebase in watchOS 2 using Cocoapods?

Tags: firebase, watchos-2

I was previously using Firebase in a Watchkit Extension, but after upgrading to Xcode7/watchOS 2 it appears that a podspec for a repo now has to specifically include support for watchOS 2 as another available platform. (And then I will have to specify this in my Podfile as well). Will this be part of the Firebase Cocoapod soon, or is there a workaround in the mean time? Or am I just doing something wrong?

With my current Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.3.3'

link_with 'watch Extension'
```

I see this warning -

"Target 'Pods' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'Pods.framework' because it doesn't contain platform 'watchsimulator' in its SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS 'iphonesimulator, iphoneos'"

Comment: Unfortunately Firebase isn't compatible with watchOS 2 because CFNetwork is available. The REST API still works however.

Comment: Did you mean CFNetwork is *not* available? That's a bummer, thanks for the info!

Comment: Yes, meant to say *not* available. It's a big bummer.